# Searching on columns and excluding codes

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to pull list of records that match "Smith" and date range and  exclude any account numbers with  codes of DD2530 and PGC.  WHen I run it, I get Smith and the date range but those codes are not getting excluded from the query.

```
select *
from [A05_AccountCommunications] a05
join (
    select distinct (a05.AccountNumber)
    from [A05_AccountCommunications] a05
    join [A01cAccountCodes] a01c on a05.accountnumber = a01c.AccountNumber
        and (a01c.codevalue not in ('dd2530'))
    join [A01cAccountCodes] a01c2 on a01c.accountnumber = a01c2.AccountNumber
        and (a01c2.codevalue not in ('PGC'))
    ) tm on a05.AccountNumber = tm.AccountNumber
where a05.date >= DATEADD(MONTH, - 24, GETDATE())
    and (
        a05.LongComment like '%Smith%'
        or a05.ShortComment like '%Smith%'
        )
order by a05.AccountNumber,
    a05.date desc
```

Comment: Please 1) tag with database platform, 2) show sample data definition, and output.  People here are not mind readers.

Comment: don't use a join to exclude use a `WHERE`

Comment: Can you give an example to put the where

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the codes in a WHERE clause instead of the ON statement. See below:

```
select *
from [A05_AccountCommunications] a05
join [A01cAccountCodes] a01c on a05.accountnumber = a01c.AccountNumber
where a05.date >= DATEADD(MONTH, - 24, GETDATE())
    and (
      a05.LongComment like '%Smith%'
      or a05.ShortComment like '%Smith%'
      )
    and a01c.codevalue not in ('dd2530', 'PGC')
order by a05.AccountNumber,
    a05.date desc
```

Comment: When I added the where statement I get the same results as my original query. I'm not sure it this matters, those two code value are different code types in the same table. That might be cause the issue?

Comment: Okay, you need to exclude in the main query too. See updated answer

Comment: it will not let me add a05.codevalue on the last where statement. The codevalue is only in the a01c table

Comment: Can you try the updated query ? I have simplified it and it should now exclude the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

EDITED to exclude duplicates.

```
select a05.*
from [A05_AccountCommunications] a05
     join (select distinct a01c.AccountNumber 
           from  [A01cAccountCodes] a01c
           where a01c.codevalue not in ('dd2530', 'PGC')
          ) ao1c  on a05.accountnumber = a01c.AccountNumber
where a05.date >= DATEADD(MONTH, - 24, GETDATE())
      and (
            a05.LongComment like '%Smith%'
            or a05.ShortComment like '%Smith%'
          )
order by a05.AccountNumber, a05.date desc
```

Comment: I'm getting a lot of the same account number  now.   I need to only one account number from a01c.accountcodes table